# Dump Block Liveness of source code using Clang

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

I need to dump the block liveness of source code using clang's API. I have tried printing the block liveness but got no success. Below is the code that I have tried

```
bool MyASTVisitor::VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {

    std::cout<<"Dump Liveness\n";
    clang::AnalysisDeclContextManager adcm;
    clang::AnalysisDeclContext *adc = adcm.getContext(llvm::cast<clang::Decl>(f));
    //clang::LiveVariables *lv = clang::LiveVariables::create(*adc);
    //clang::LiveVariables *lv = clang::LiveVariables::computeLiveness(*adc,false);
    clang::LiveVariables *lv = adc->getAnalysis<LiveVariables>();
    clang::LiveVariables::Observer *obs = new clang::LiveVariables::Observer();

    lv->runOnAllBlocks(*obs);

    lv->dumpBlockLiveness((f->getASTContext()).getSourceManager());

    return true;
}
```

I have override Visitor Functions and have tried printing the liveness of a function. I have tried using create, computeLiveness and getAnalysis methods to get the LiveVariables object, but all the approaches failed. However no Liveness Information is displayed except the block numbers.

When I use command line arguments of clang to print the liveness it displays the output correctly.

I am using the following source code as test case taken from [Live Variable Analysis Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis#Second_example)
.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a,b,c,d,x;

  a = 3;  
  b = 5;
  d = 4;
  x = 100;

  if(a>b){
    c = a+b;
    d = 2;
  }

  c = 4; 
  return b * d + c;
}
```

Could someone please point out where could I be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, after some debugging of `clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpLiveVars` I finally found the answer !

The issue is that the `LiveVariables` analysis does not explores sub-expressions (such as `DeclRefExpr`) by itself. It only relies on the CFG enumeration. By default the CFG only enumerates top-level statements.

You must call `adc->getCFGBuildOptions().setAllAlwaysAdd()` before getting any analysis from your `AnalysisDeclContext`. This will create elements for all sub-expressions in the `CFGBlocks` of the control-flow-graph.

Comment: However this does not seem to work for clang 3.1. Works on clang 3.8.